# Not able to generate Activity Indicator same as Pull to refresh indicator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview, pull-to-refresh

I am using a PullToRefresh activity indicator in my app. But somewhere I have used UIActivityIndicatorView, it's size is smaller than PullToRefresh Indicator. Is there any way to get the same size and color as a PullToRefresh indicator?
I tried to modify UIActivityIndicatorView but is worthless.
Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView! {
        didSet {
            if activityIndicator != nil {
                let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.0, y: 0.75)
                activityIndicator.transform = transform
            }
        }
    }
```

**I want output like this**

[image]

**My current view is like this**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying `size` property to `.whiteLarge`

```
activityIndicator.size = .whiteLarge
```

You can change the color according to your need by setting the `tintColor` property.

[appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview/style/whitelarge)